# Make base method required in derived class

Tags: c#

I am in the process of building some classes, and i have a method in the base class that needs to be included in the deriving classes implementation of the method.

How do i get this performed?

### For Example:

```
public class base{
  public base(){}

  public void Method(base val){
    //Logic implementation
  }
}

public class derive:base{
  public derive():base(){}

  public void Method(derive val){
    base.Method(val);
    
    //Logic implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems you've answered your own question.  To include the base class implementation of a method, you just call `base.Method(val)` from inside the derived method.  What else is missing?

Comment: its more of making sure that the base method is being called.  Right now i have close to 10-15 classes that have various chains of inheritance.  Its a nicety, more convenience, if the base method call would already be called and or require the template signature of the method to be built when i do my inheritence.

Comment: that 10-15 will quickly jump to 50 or so....so going for the minimal amount of keypushes....FYI the value-type for the parameter is the name of the class it is included.  Which gives the second problem, of auto data-typing a method, without a Interface ;)

Comment: have an interface already, designed with Generics....just every class has a base class inheritance and the Interface.  Want to get it down to just 1 inheritance for each new class and get the functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Since you want actual functionality in the base class and augment that functionality in the derived class I would suggest having a public method in the base class that can be called which in turn calls an abstract method that is implemented in the derived class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
  public BaseClass(){}

  public void Method(int val)
  {
      //base class logic here
      //now call DoSomething implementation
      DoSomething(val);
      //some other base class logic here
  }

  protected abstract void DoSomething(int val);
}

public class Derived : BaseClass
{
    protected override void DoSomething(int val)
    {
       //other logic
    }
}
```

This pattern is known as a [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) or Non-Virtual Interface (NVI) pattern.

Comment: Its my understanding that you cant derive from abstract classes....so should i have a abstract class created with the "template" and then create a instantiable class from the abstract and then derive from both the base and abstract?

Comment: you cannot instantiate an abstract class, but you can of course derive from it (otherwise it would be useless).

Comment: @GoldBishop: Your understanding is wrong. The whole *point* of an abstract class is that you derive from it, and provide implementations of any abstract members.

Comment: thats what i need to have that understanding....MSDN is lacking (no surprise) and all other sources mirror MSDN.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: looking at doing `public abstract class ABase` then `public class Base:ABase` with eventual `public class Derive:Base, ABase` if necessary, prefer: `public class Derive:Base`

Comment: why does `Derive` need to derive from both Base and ABase?

Answer (score 1):

Make the method [`abstract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx).

```
public class base{
  public base(){}

  public abstract void Method(base val);
}
```

In the derived class you need to mark the method with `override`

```
public override void Method(derive val){
```

If you want to create a default implementation in the base class you mark the method `virtual` instead of `abstract`, but then you can not demand that derived classes implement that method.

Comment: side note .net 3.5, at least, does not allow abstract methods in a non-abstract class.  Tried that but the problem is also that the base class has its own properties that are being opearated on that carry over to the deriving class.  Hence the need to have the base class have full implementation and the deriving class call the base class method before doing its own implementation.

Comment: im relatively new to the csharp arena....i know in VB, if i had a derived method, it would auto-load a mybase.method() implementation in a method and required the inclusiong of the base method in the derived class for it to be valid, is there a similar way to do this in csharp?